# Embedded Tomcat 8 Application Configured Programmatically

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

Is there a way to create an application with embedded Tomcat 8 that is configured programmatically (not through a web.xml)? I'm trying to start this application via main() and not through Maven's Tomcat plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but Tomcat 8 supports Servlet spec 3.1.  Anything after spec 3.0 (tomcat 7) can implement a ServletContainerInitializer.  This should give you what you want.

```
public class ServletInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext cx) {
   // register stuff here
}
```